# How to Send Java Spring logger.info Messages Back to Angular For Display

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, logging

I am currently looking for a way to send Java logger.info messages from a Spring Controller back to the front end, to be listened and displayed by AngularJS and then bound to an ng-model.

Is there any way to broadcast logger.info messages to the front end to be displayed in the ng-model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create **Websocket Server** using Java to throw all the logging messages. You can use **Socket Io client** in AngularJs which will receive live logging messages from Java and display in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

On the font end, use something like `angular-websocket` as a **message receiver**.

On the backend, if you use log4j, just extends your own `WriterAppender` as a **message sender** and make some change with config properties. If you use other log components, do something like this.